# Edit list of Google accounts offered at login prompt

Tags: google-account

Google has changed the order of the suggested accounts in the list it offers when I log in. I want to reorder them so my personal account defaults to the top.
I haven't been able to find the answer in related questions about removing specific accounts from the list. It appears the user interface has changed again so the answers don't match up with what I am seeing and I can't find a place to edit the order of the accounts.

Does anyone know how to edit the accounts listed (add/remove/reorder accounts) when Google prompts you to log in?

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify where you are logging in. Maybe provide the URL.  Is this browser-specific or app-specific?